# Redirect a non-existing url to error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all non available links to the error.php page

**here is what I want**

if someone entered a link that does not exist ,then instead of 404 Error page of webhost , I want to redirect them to my error page

```
 www.example.com/wrong_page.php
```

should be redirected to

```
 www.example.com/error.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options to redirect a Wrong `REQUEST_URI` to the error page

**1)** Internal Redirect

Your web server will internally redirect a wrong request  to the error page,

Try this in your  `WebRoot/.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error.php [NC,L]
```

**2)** External Redirect

Your web server will externally redirect a wrong request  to the error page,

Or Try this in your  `WebRoot/.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/error.php [R,NC,L]
```

Rewrite conditions check if the Requested filename is not a directory or file ,then RewriteRule will Redirect it to the error page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this directive to your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many type of error page (just google it). You can handle them using .htaccess. For Example

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html

ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.html

ErrorDocument 401 /errordocs/401.html

ErrorDocument 403 /errordocs/403.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up in your `.htaccess` file. You can use [.htaccess generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) or simply just add this line to a new .htaccess file:

```
//Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 error.php
```

Apart from just the error page, you may also want to disable directory listing or change the default page of a directory. For all that, a .htaccess file is used. If you are new to it, simply use the link I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my .htaccess

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

IndexIgnore */*

ErrorDocument 400 /err_400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /err_401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /err_403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /err_404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /err_500.php
```