# Redirect wrong urls to 404 page

Tags: php

How to redirect wrong urls to 404 page?

For example, `subdomain.domain.com` is fine, but if users enter `subdomain.domain.com/asadasd/ada` or anything like that, index page is still shown. How to make these mistyped urls show 404 page?

Im using php, mysql, cpanel ect ect.

Yes, I am already using htaccess with `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php` but no luck here.

Comment: Use htaccess.It will help you]

Comment: This has been asked many times before.  Here is one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669323/redirect-a-non-existing-url-to-error-page/29669402#29669402)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189169/redirect-to-404-page-or-display-404-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use '.htaccess' 
put this line in .htaccess `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php` and create `error.php` file in your root folder.

Comment: The error documents defined using the ErrorDocument directive are only served when the web server recognizes that the request cannot be mapped onto an existing file. Please make sure the OP is not using the mod_rewrite

Comment: I am already doing that, but still nothing. I dont use rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

You will handle the redirection with .htaccess errordocument 404 /404.php
Please follow the complete process in this link
It  will help you a lot.
[error redirection link tutorials](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-redirect-old-urls-php/)